# will restarting apache clear my memcache contents?

Tags: apache, apache2, memcached

I just wanted to know if memcache is linked to apache or it runs as a separate process. So, will restarting apache clear my memcache contents or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Memcache is not linked to the apache process.  Memcached is a separate process.

HOWEVER, your application framework if you are using one, may flush memcache if you restart apache.

-daniel

Comment: +1, great.. what would be the typical name for the memcache process in an unix environment?

Answer (score 10):

You can also empty memcached without restarting it:

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

11211 it the default port for memcached (if nothing responds on this port check your init script)

And within telnet:

```
flush_all
```

This will flush all stored data.

Comment: +1.. good information.. where would the init script for memcached be??

Comment: On RHEL linux (that's what I'm using) the init script is in /etc/init.d/memcached. The configuration (port, allocated memory, users etc) is read from /etc/memcached.conf

Answer (score 0):

restarting the server will flush all stored data

```
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```